# PHP - preg_match to validate date format mm/yyyy

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

For the check of the birthday date (format: dd/mm/yyyy) in my form I've used this code and it works fine.

```
if (!preg_match("/([012]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/([0-9]{4})/",$date)){    
  $error[1]= "Insert a valid date";
}
```

But when I want to check a date with the format mm/yyyy and I use this code, it doesn't work anymore. When I try for example to put 33/2014 in my input my php validation doesn't show it as an error.

```
if (!preg_match("/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/([0-9]{4})/",$date2)){  
  $error[2]= "Insert a valid date";
}
```

Where do I go wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: "doesn't work" usually needs some concretization, sample input. Is your question about absent regex start/end anchors?

Comment: An comment: `preg_match` return `integer` or `boolean` (if have error in REGEXP), Read more in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php I know this has to do with the question, just a hint same.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento is right. Even if your regex were correct you might not get the result you excepct.

Comment: It is typically a million times (at least) easier/better to just have three fields for birthdate or some sort of calendar. Then you know the format is exactly what you are expecting because there are sooo many formats for dates and every country does it different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Tim's [checkdate](https://www.php.net/checkdate) based solution:

The extraction of day, month and year can easily be done using explode as:

```
list($dd,$mm,$yyyy) = explode('/',$cnt_birthday);
if (!checkdate($mm,$dd,$yyyy)) {
        $error = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is invalid and even if it were correct you might run into some trouble with you comparison as preg_match returns in most cases an integer and not a boolean.

Simple and not so clean way:

```
function checkMyDate($date) {
    $components = explode('/', $date);
    if(count($components) !== 2) return false;
    return checkdate($components[0], 1, $components[1]);
}
```

Posssibly preffered option:

However, php has builtin functionality to work with dates. If `DateTime` can handle the string given you should be alright:

```
function checkDateByFormat($date, $format = 'n/Y') {
    $t = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

    if($t === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return $t->format($format) === $date;
}

var_dump(checkDateByFormat('12/2014')); // true
var_dump(checkDateByFormat('13/2014')); // false
var_dump(checkDateByFormat('12/20149')); // false
var_dump(checkDateByFormat('1/e1')); // false
var_dump(checkDateByFormat('7/1982')); // true
```

Related to [this](http://php.net/manual/de/function.checkdate.php#113205) post but taken from my own code dumpster.